# Lualatex Tikz externalize error in scrartcle class

Tags: luatex, tikz-external

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- ++(2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When compiling this with `lualatex -shell-escape externalizeTest.tex`, it results in the error (in my case the file is named `externalizeTest.tex`)

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "externalize-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalre
aljob{externalize}\input{externalize}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 
'externalize-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify th
at you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape
'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the c
ommand simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'externalize-figure0.log'.
 If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

If however I change the `documentclass` to `standalone`, everything works like charm.

The same applies if I use `pdflatex` instead of `lualatex` to compile the document.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Now even though I don't know *why* this happens, I have found a solution to the problem (see also [Cannot run tikz externalize with lualatex but it used to work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365777/cannot-run-tikz-externalize-with-lualatex-but-it-used-to-work)):

If I also include the `shellesc` package, the document compiles just fine with `lualatex` as well (with the `scrartcle` class). The MWE then looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\usepackage{shellesc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- ++(2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Now I *think* that I have read once that `lualatex` handles shell-escaping differently than `pdflatex` and thus one has to include the `shellesc` package in order to make it compatible with "the normal way" of doing it.

As to why it worked with `standalone`, my best guess would be that this class implicitly includes the `shellesc` package. I don't actually have proof of this though.

If someone knows what's actually going on, it'd be great if you could comment or even write an answer of your own...

Comment: You can easily check if standalone loads shellesc: look in the log-file. Beside this your example works fine in current texlive even without shellesc, imho tikz adapted the calls at some time.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah that's good to know. Thank you :)